# Configuration file for Apache2 and two websites

Tags: apache, web, apache2

I have two domains and this is my configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin hello@example.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
 ServerName main-site.example
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin hello@example.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html/
 ServerName second-site.example
</VirtualHost>
```

What I do not understand is this:

- `main-site.example` and `www.main-site.example` are accesible and point at `main-site.example`, so this is ok
- but `www.second-site.example` points to `main-site.example` only if I do `second-site.example` it works and I do not understand why

Answer (score 0):

Add the `ServerAlias` directive to define your virtualHosts. Otherwise Apache will match `www.second-site.example` with the first `*:80` `VirtualHost`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName main-site.example
  ServerAlias www.main-site.example
  ServerAdmin hello@example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName second-site.example
 ServerAlias www.second-site.example 
 ServerAdmin hello@example.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html/
</VirtualHost>
```